# Converting MS Office documents (DOC&DOCX) into LaTeX by w2l in command lines of linux

Tags: conversion, msword, open-office

I want to convert `MS Office` documents(DOC&DOCX) into `LaTeX`!

I need to do two steps to finish the conversion.

The first step is to convert the MS Office documents into `libreoffice(ODT)` by `libreoffice4.2 odt:"writer8"  *.DOCX`.

The second step is to convert  `libreoffice(ODT)` into `LaTeX` by `w2l -config writer2latex.xml *.odt`, which uses command `xetex` and this command support Chinese.

Actually I am able to finish the first step but I face some problems in the second step.

the formulas inputted by Mathtype  and images  have been converted the format of .svm, which can be opened in `libreoffice(ODT)`. However, the `LaTeX` can't recognize `.svm`, which drives me crazy.

PS:This step is finished successfully. In the second step, if I open ODT produced in the first step in `libreoffice(ODT)` and export `.tex` using `writer2latex extension`, then the formulas inputted by Mathtype  and images  have been converted the format of .pdf, which can be recognized by `LaTeX`. The `.tex` can be compiled using `xetex *.tex`.

All the operations are executed in the environment of `debian 7.5 , texlive2013`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, as written [in the documentation of Writer2LaTeX for command line usage](http://writer2latex.sourceforge.net/doc1.4/user-manual12.html),

> Limitation: The export filters support conversion of embedded objects and graphics to a suitable format. The command line utility can only handle graphics in the original format.

Hence, using the `w2l` command-line produces those `.svm` files. If you want to keep working with the command-line and not to have to launch OpenOffice (or [LibreOffice](https://libreoffice.org), for that matter), you can use [unoconv](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv). A simple

```
unoconv -f pdf input-file001.svm
```

will produce a `input-file001.pdf` that you might want to crop using

```
pdfcrop input-file001.pdf
```

you can then include your document using

```
\includegraphics{input-file001-crop.pdf}
```

You can have a look at a [related question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/q/873962/446943).